# How to use getElementsByTagName for specific node in Minidom

Tags: python-3.x, xml, elementtree, getelementsbytagname, minidom

My XML looks like this

```
<TOPIC>
    <LIST>
        <Area>JKH</Area>
        <USED>
            <type id='123' />
            <type id='345' />
        </USED>
        <DEMAND>
            <type id='809' />
            <type id='321' />
        </DEMAND>
        <CLOSED>
            <type id='456' />
            <type id='765' />
        </CLOSED>
    </LIST>
</TOPIC>
```

Here i want to print only the `id` under `<DEMAND>`. i have tried the below code.

```
from xml.dom import minidom
root=minidom.parse('sample.xml')
tag=root.getElementsByTagName('type')
for i in tag: 
    print(i.getAttribute("id"))
```

But this is printing all the `id` values like below.

```
123
345
809
321
456
765
```

How can i get only `809` & `321` that are under `<DEMAND>` tag. I can give path in `ElementTree` but not sure how to give in `getElementsByTagName` ? Is it even possible in Minidom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for demand in root.getElementsByTagName('DEMAND'):
    for tp in demand.getElementsByTagName('type'):
        print(tp.getAttribute("id"))
```

Comment: Great. This is what i am looking for

Comment: @Avinash The more complex the requirements get, the more beneficial it is to pick a DOM implementation that supports XPath (such as ElementTree). The XPath `//DEMAND/type/@id` would have replaced this nested loop.

Comment: That's a very valid point. I will make a note of it.